# How to start byobu everytime I start a terminal when using zsh as default shell?

Tags: command-line, byobu, zsh

I'm using zsh as my default shell.

I installed byobu and it seems to work fine, however I have to launch it manually every time I start a terminal instance (`Ctrl+Alt+T`).

I checked byobu-config and it says

> Byobu currently launches at login (toggle off)

But it's not the case. I tried toggling this option, but it doesn't change anything and I still have to run `byobu` whenever I start a terminal.

Is there a way of forcing byobu to be launched whenevr I start a terminal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't use zsh but I had this problem with the standard terminal application on Ubuntu and Linux Mint (gnome-terminal). I believe that the 'byobu-config' command only enables byobu for remote log-in, for example through ssh. In my case byobu-config had added the following line at the end of ~/.profile to enable byobu for remote log-ins:

```
_byobu_sourced=1 . /usr/bin/byobu-launch 2>/dev/null || true
```

I added the same line to the end of ~/.bashrc and it then worked for the local terminal too. Presumably zsh has a similar configuration file that you can edit.

Comment: this line is added when you launch `byobu-enable` command, but I doesn't work for me.